# Deceptive Site Navigation Warning on Android App - Clarification Needed

Tags: android, user-interface, google-play, admob, adsense

I recently received a Deceptive Site Navigation warning from Admob for my backup & restore app. The warning mentions a potential issue with deceptive navigation on a specific screen. Attached is a screenshot of the screen in question.

The screen contains buttons for deleting and uploading items, a checkbox for multiple selections, and an AdMob banner at the top. I observed that the delete button appears to perform its functionality even when there is no content available to delete. Clicking delete in such scenarios displays a message saying "Deleted Successfully," which might be misleading.

Screenshot:
[image: Contact Backup Fragment]

Issue:

Admob ads got limited

Question:

Could the observed behavior of the delete button lead to a Deceptive Site Navigation warning?

I attempted to address the Deceptive Site Navigation warning by appealing to Google Play, providing an explanation of the app's functionality. However, the appeal was not successful.

I am seeking assistance to understand whether the observed behavior of the delete button, performing its functionality even when there is no content available to delete, could be a contributing factor to the Deceptive Site Navigation warning.